# Extract the first quoted string of each line of a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, text-extraction

I want to read through a text file with a lot of lines.
in the beginning of each line, i have a string between quotes, then a coma and then the rest of the lines, Ex.:

```
"CBL003","C3/C5 // <>SdcdUB","",0,1,"PfcdDT_gerergv","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",
"CBL004","C3<.<C7 // <>SqsxUB","",0,1,"PDzesdxT_esfdczec","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,""
```

What I want is to read through the file, and extract the first line put it in a different text file and name it with the first strings of the line that it contains. Ex.:
In the above example, I should have the text file  CBL003.txt that contains:

```
"CBL003","C3/C5 // <>SdcdUB","",0,1,"PfcdDT_gerergv","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",
```

and a second file text CBL004.txt that contains :

```
"CBL004","C3<.<C7 // <>SqsxUB","",0,1,"PDzesdxT_esfdczec","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,"","",0,""
```

I already have a code that read through each line :

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (C:\SourceFile.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%a 
)
```

But I don't know how to extract the first part of each line

Comment: You could try using the regex `\"(.*?)\"` and return the first match, providing that your data is always at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `tokens=1` because you want `%%a` to be set to only the first token, and you need `delims=,` to specify the comma as the delimiter. You can remove the quotes, if you want, by using `%%~a`. Type `for /?` for help.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%a IN (C:\SourceFile.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%~a
)
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for thanks. So the tokens=1 is to mean that I only want the first string before my delimiter. So for the %%~a, whenever we want the extraction without quotes we add ~ right ?

Comment: Yes, normally the quotes are placed around filenames that contain spaces, and the ~ is used to remove them from the variable. But it doesn't have to be a filename, as it works with any string.